# front end login

Tags: control-panel, login

I have a login on my front end, if a member logs in and then clicks on a link to "edit_this" which is the shortcut to the back end to edit the entry, why do they have to login again on the back end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely because they are logged in with `www.domain.com` but visiting the cp with `domain.com` or visa versa.

The solution is to adjust the Cookie settings for the EE install. Specifically, set a [**Cookie Domain**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/cookie_settings.html#cookie-domain) so the member's logged in session will be used across both URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Anna's solution is good. You could also utilise your htaccess file to always run the site with or without the www